# kernel configs and dependencies

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

When a particular kernel config is turned on, e.g.

```
CONFIG_CRYPTO_FIPS=y
```

a bunch of other dependencies (`CONFIG_XXX_YYYY`) get turned on during compilation. Is there a way to know all the dependencies for a given kernel CONFIG_ ?

Answer (score 4):

The `Depends on` section in `menuconfig` is stored in `Kconfig` files' `depends on` sections.

```
config CRYPTO_FIPS  
        bool "FIPS 200 compliance"  
        depends on (CRYPTO_ANSI_CPRNG || CRYPTO_DRBG) && !CRYPTO_MANAGER_DISABLE_TESTS  
        depends on MODULE_SIG   
        help     
          This options enables the fips boot option which is     
          required if you want to system to operate in a FIPS 200    
          certification. You should say no unless you know what      
          this is.
```

You can read the Kconfig files and search out the config.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the `ncurses` based configuration (`make menuconfig`) just search your particular kernel option (press `/` then type `CONFIG_CRYPTO_FIPS`) and it's dependencies will also be listed in there. For instance in my 3.13 kernel tree I get:

```
Symbol: CRYPTO_FIPS [=n]                                                                                                                                 
Type  : boolean                                                                                                                                       
Prompt: FIPS 200 compliance                                                                                                                           
Location:                                                                                                                                           
(1) -> Cryptographic API (CRYPTO [=y])                                                                                                                
  Defined at crypto/Kconfig:24                                                                                                                        
  Depends on: CRYPTO [=y] && CRYPTO_ANSI_CPRNG [=n] && !CRYPTO_MANAGER_DISABLE_TESTS [=y]
```

Comment: Yes, this is one option, but `menuconfig` needs graphics, which is not always available on all servers.

Answer (score -2):

`CONFIG_CRYPTO_FIPS`

This options enables the fips boot option which is
required if you want to system to operate in a FIPS 200
certification. You should say no unless you know what
this is.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question. The question was about finding the dependencies of any particular configuration option not about describing what `CONFIG_CRYPTO_FIPS` does ...

Comment: Thanks for your concern, but I know what this is. As @dragosht said, this doesn't answer my question.